# The method is undefined for the type (object)

Tags: java

I have three objects each with an individual integer assigned to them.

```
Food hamburger = new Food();
hamburger.calories = 500;
Food spaghetti = new Food();
spaghetti.calories = 700;
Food sausage = new Food();
sausage.calories = 300;
```

And then a method to compare which food has the lowest calories.

```
public Food findLowestCalories(Food f1, Food f2, Food f3) {

    if (f1.calories < f2.calories && f1.calories < f3.calories){
        return f1;
    } else if (f2.calories < f1.calories && f2.calories < f3.calories){
        return f2;
    } else {
        return f3;
    }

}
```

Then I have a line to print out the result of findLowestCalories:

```
System.out.println(findLowestCalories(hamburger, spaghetti, sausage));
```

I am getting an error: The method findLowestCalories(Food, Food, Food) is undefined for the type FoodEater.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit:**

So FoodEater looks like this:

public class Food Eater {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Food hamburger = new Food();
    hamburger.calories = 500;
    Food spaghetti = new Food();
    spaghetti.calories = 700;
    Food sausage = new Food();
    sausage.calories = 300;

    System.out.println(findLowestCalories(hamburger, spaghetti, sausage));

}
```

}

and my other class like this:

```
public class FoodMeasure {

public Food findLowestCalories(Food f1, Food f2, Food f3) {

    if (f1.calories < f2.calories && f1.calories < f3.calories){
        return f1;
    } else if (f2.calories < f1.calories && f2.calories < f3.calories){
        return f2;
    } else {
        return f3;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Hard to help within seeing your `FoodEater.java` class, but the error seems self-explanatory

Comment: We don't have enough information to help you... What is FoodEater? A class, is the method findLowestCalories inside of the class?

Comment: It mean you have a class called FoodEater... you should paste the code of that as well to see what incompatible variables/objects you are passing

Comment: Please edit with the code, not an explanation.

Comment: *and the method FindLowestCalories is in another public class* -- Yeah. That's the exact problem the error is telling you

Comment: I have added both classes in full in an edit - I was under the impression I could use methods in other classes without doing anything special?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 1) Move the method into `FoodEater`. Need to also declare as `static` (for reasons....)

```
public static Food findLowestCalories(Food f1, Food f2, Food f3) {
```

Option 2) Declare an instance of the class so that you *can* call that method.

```
FoodMeasure measure = new FoodMeasure();
System.out.println(measure.findLowestCalories(hamburger, spaghetti, sausage));
```

Option 3) No external methods. Move all the logic of `findLowestCalories` into the `main` method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to construct of an object `FoodMeasure` and invoke the `findLowestCalories` method through that object.  Example:

```
    FoodMeasure foodMeasure = new FoodMeasure();

    System.out.println(foodMeasure.findLowestCalories(hamburger, spaghetti, sausage));
```